# Is there a way to define a remove eventhandler function just like there is to define property getters and setters?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a class that exposes an event named `valueChanged`. I'm presently doing so:

```
this.valueChanged = undefined;
this.valueChangedListeners = [];

Object.defineProperty(this, "valueChanged", {
        set: function(v) {
                if (!(v instanceof Function)) {
                        throw new Error("Invalid value provided for Asset.valueChanged.");
                }

                // add to the listeners
                this.valueChangedListeners.push(v);
        }
});
```

Now, to remove an event listener, I have three options:

1. I could either add a new interface named `RemoveValueChangedEventListener`. Or
2. I could remove the `valueChanged` property and replace it with a symmetric set of `addValueChangedEventListener` and `removeValueChangedEventListener` methods. Or
3. I could adhere to the [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) interface and keep a set of events. So, I'd have just two symmetric methods named `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` and the client could then add an event handler for the `valueChanged` event like so:

---

```
var asset = new Asset("Goodwill",  // asset name
                fixedAssets, // asset group
                120000);  // value

asset.addEventListener("valueChanged", function(event) {
  ...
});
```

However, I was wondering if there is already a keyword like `add` and `remove` to set for adding and removing event listeners, just like there are for defining property getters and setters. Just like C# has the `add` and `remove` syntactic sugar for adding and removing methods to a delegate?

Comment: So you're basically asking how to remove an element from the `valueChangedListeners` array? It's not very clear what is the problem you're trying to solve and what the issue is.

Comment: Symmetric methods sound the best to me - use a `Set` if you can (more appropriate than an array, and easier to remove elements from it). But I'm not sure what exactly your question is - a collection of event listeners (or other handlers) isn't inherently different from a collection of anything else, you can implement any sort of interface you want for adding/removing elements

Comment: Also note that in your `3`'s sample code, such an added listener wouldn't be able to be removed later because the function is anonymous and not saved anywhere.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Thank you. I think you've answered my question. Thanks for pointing to the memory leak in #3. That was an oversight. In production, I would have cached the listener. :-)

Comment: @Adelin: No, I wasn't asking how to remove an element from an array. I was asking if the JavaScript language provided a set of keywords to `add` and `remove` event listeners, just like it does for defining property getters and setters. Basically, that was all. I got the answer from CertainPerformance's comments that there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't any keywords to add and remove event listeners. @CertainPerformance's comments to the question seem to suggest that. He suggests that I use the property getters and setters to add and remove events, but that doesn't make sense to me.

So, the neatest way, perhaps, is to use the symmetrical `EventTarget` like interface.

```
Asset.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, listener) {
    if (eventName !== "valueChanged") {
        return false;
    }

    if (!(listener instanceof Function)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid value provided for Asset.valueChanged event listener. Function expected.");
    }

    // add to the listeners
    this.valueChangedListeners.push(listener);
});

Asset.prototype.removeEventListener = function(eventName, listener) {
    if (eventName !== "valueChanged") {
        return false;
    }

    if (!(listener instanceof Function)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid value provided for Asset.valueChanged event listener. Function expected.");
    }

    if (!(listener of this.valueChangedListeners)) {
        return;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < this.valueChangedListeners.length; i++) {
        if (this.valueChangedListeners[i] === listener) {
            this.valueChangedListeners.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I was referring to a `Set`, which is a (somewhat) unordered collection of items. Add items with `Set.add(item)` and remove with `Set.delete(item)`, which is a *lot* nicer than using an array and looping through it to find the matching index and then splicing that index. (This is completely different from setters and getters inside objects)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks. That's a good idea but wouldn't that disallow the same handler being added twice?

Comment: Ah, so it would, but that is actually the same behavior that the native `addEventListener` exhibits: https://jsfiddle.net/0suepvk3/

Comment: Thank you. That is very interesting. :-)